# How to compress Image if the size is greater than 2MB

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, base64, compression

I am working on image compression and I have a requirement to compress the photo if the image size is greater than 2MB.

Use case:

- If the size is 1.9MB do nothing
- If the size is 3MB or 5MB or 10MB then compress the image so that its size is less than 2MB always. (I am having trouble with this one)

If there is any solution, I would appreciate it.

```
$("#photo").change(function () {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e) => {
        const imgElement = document.createElement("img");
        imgElement.src = event.target.result;
        document.querySelector("#input").src = event.target.result;

        imgElement.onload = function (evt) {
            console.log(evt);
            const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            const MAX_WIDTH = 400;
            const scaleSize = MAX_WIDTH / evt.target.width;

            canvas.width = MAX_WIDTH;

            canvas.height = evt.target.height * scaleSize;


            const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(evt.target, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            const srcEncoded = ctx.canvas.toDataURL(evt.target, "image/jpeg");

            document.querySelector("#output").src = srcEncoded;

            reader.onload = () => srcEncoded = reader.result;
        }
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
});
```

Comment: Why do you want to decrease the size? If it is to better handle them and faster load them you have to do so on the server not in the client code.

Comment: @Alinex I want to decrease the size because we are saving the image in DB as blob. So, we dont want to save 10MB images in DB instead we would like to compress them and save.